# Eliminating decimals from whole numbers only

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column with a range of numbers.

```
row1: 3.4
row2: 4.00
row3: 5.23
row4: 2.0
row5: 0.00
row6: 000
```

I would like the final result to be

```
row1: 3.4
row2: 4
row3: 5.23
row4: 2
row5: 0
row6: 0
```

I basically want to remove decimals if it's a whole number or 0.

Comment: What's the type of the column?

Comment: its a character field (varchar2)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a reason you want to use PL/SQL instead of a SQL solution?

Comment: SQL solution works just fine. I have tried using round and trunc functions after converting it to a number field. But I can't use these functions selectively to eliminate decimals from just whole numbers.

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? And what do you want to see for say `'00.10'` ?

Comment: I extracted the numbers from a string so just keeping it as a string. It can be stored as numbers. For 00.10, it should be seen as 0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method, assuming they are all represent valid numbers, is just to convert them from strings to numbers and back again:

```
with t (id, str) as (
            select 1, '3.4' from dual
  union all select 2, '4.00' from dual
  union all select 3, '5.23' from dual
  union all select 4, '2.0' from dual
  union all select 5, '0.00' from dual
  union all select 6, '000' from dual
)
select id, str, to_char(to_number(str)) as result
from t;

        ID STR  RESULT                                  
---------- ---- ----------------------------------------
         1 3.4  3.4                                     
         2 4.00 4                                       
         3 5.23 5.23                                    
         4 2.0  2                                       
         5 0.00 0                                       
         6 000  0
```

That will show an initial value of `0.1` as just `.1`; if you want to preserve the leading zero in that case you could use:

```
rtrim(to_char(to_number(str), 'FM999999990.99999'), '.')
```

supplying a format mask with enough leading and trailing `9` placeholders for your data:

```
with t (id, str) as (
            select 1, '3.4' from dual
  union all select 2, '4.00' from dual
  union all select 3, '5.23' from dual
  union all select 4, '2.0' from dual
  union all select 5, '0.00' from dual
  union all select 6, '000' from dual
  union all select 7, '01' from dual
  union all select 8, '00.10' from dual
)
select id, str, rtrim(to_char(to_number(str), 'FM999999990.99999'), '.') as result
from t;

        ID STR   RESULT          
---------- ----- ----------------
         1 3.4   3.4             
         2 4.00  4               
         3 5.23  5.23            
         4 2.0   2               
         5 0.00  0               
         6 000   0               
         7 01    1               
         8 00.10 0.1
```

Another option is to just convert to a number in your query and let the client or whatever else consumes this decide how to format it.